# could not find XapCacheFile.xml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When debugging the my application using visual studio 10 , I receive the following error ...

```
" Error 1   Could not find file 'C:\Users\Aksi\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\vimol\vimol\obj\Debug\XapCacheFile.xml'. Please rebuild the solution and try again.".. 

" Error 1   Xap packaging failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. vimol"
```

It's a Windows Phone application... I made it using Microsoft Expression Blend...

Answer (score 1):

Close Blend, open `C:\Users\Aksi\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\vimol\vimol\` and remove both `bin` and `obj` subfolders.

Open the project in Blend again and try to build it!

Comment: I had exactly the same issue after creation of new WP8 project, when running in a fresh installed VS Express 2000 for Windows Phone.

Comment: Removing folders bin and obj and rebuild from Blend (Project->Build Project) did the trick. Afterwards emulator starts the app like a sharm.